# Show a Form into a Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, unit-testing

Our application is really complex and is mainly displaying some graphics.
During the creation of the Unit Test we need a way to view our "preparation datas".

To do this, we have create a 'windows form' able to paint our data.

The problem is that, when we try to show the window, nothing appear !

Here is what I tried

```
public void Draw()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    //Application.Run(this);
    this.BringToFront();
    this.Focus();
    this.ShowDialog();
}
```

Do you have any idea to display such window in the context of the Unit Test project ?

Comment: i wouldn't. the form can block your unit test from finishing

Comment: Don't. Unit testing is not the right context to do this kind of work. Unit tests are meant to be run headless and are not designed, either fundamentally or technically, to be interactive.

Comment: I know... I don't care ! It is only to "visualy" chek if the datas are correct !
It it only used during data preparation (which can be very complex). It is just a "tool". Thanks